# C# best approach to add new item in existing LinkedList<T>?

Tags: c#, list, linked-list

I am trying to add new movie name in the existing linked list but got error.

```
cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<string>'
```

Here is code I am working on it:

```
 LinkedList<string>  movies = new LinkedList<string>();
       movies.AddLast("Fire & Dew");
       movies.AddLast("Hang Break");
       movies.AddLast("Naughty Monkey");
       movies.AddLast("Sabotage");  

     //Add movie name Good & Bad After Hang Break
     movies.AddAfter("Hang Break", "Good & Bad");

        foreach (string movie in movies)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(movie);
       }
```

Any solution and code tip?

Comment: For each element in doubly linked list, you need refrence for next and previous items. you are required a seprate type
to encapsulate the element. That type is LinkedListNode<T>.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a linked list and not another collection type?

Comment: Rule #1: never use LinkedList.  Rule #2: use it properly, AddAfter() requires a node, not a string.  Making it work with a string would make it worse than it already is, you'd have to iterate the collection again to find the node.  Use List<> instead.

Comment: Linked List provide an alternative collection that gives better performance for the situation where you need to add or remove items from a collection very frequently.

Comment: That is a very common misconception.  Finding the insertion point back is *more* expensive than inserting an element in a List.  LinkedList is very unfriendly to modern processors, it has very poor cache locality.  You can only be ahead if you don't lose the node reference, actually what the OP forgot to do.

Answer (score 7):

Well the *type signature* of [`AddAfter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8adh33dd(v=vs.110).aspx) is:

> ```
> public LinkedListNode<T> AddAfter(LinkedListNode<T> node, T value)
> ```

So the first parameter `node` should be a `LinkedListNode<T>`. You can obtain that node since it is returned from the [`AddLast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132177(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
movies.AddLast("Fire & Dew");
var hang_break = movies.AddLast("Hang Break");
movies.AddLast("Naughty Monkey");
movies.AddLast("Sabotage");  

//Add movie name Good & Bad After Hang Break
movies.AddAfter(hang_break, "Good & Bad");
```

After we've evaluated this code in the `csharp` interactive shell, we obtain:

```
csharp> movies
{ "Fire & Dew", "Hang Break", "Good & Bad", "Naughty Monkey", "Sabotage" }
```

The reason why this is necessary is because such linked list allows insertion next to the *given* node in *O(1)* since it modifies the references of the next and previous node. This can be done since it only needs to alter the given node and the node next to the given node. If you however first need to search the node, then the algorithm is *O(n)* and so the performance advantage of a linked list will be lost.